# Debug mostrando nome e valor da variável?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debug

Muitas vezes quando preciso depurar o valor de uma variável em tempo de execução eu uso o `print()`.

Mas quando há muitas variáveis, preciso identificar o nome da variável junto com o valor.

Desta forma, **o print vai ficando mais trabalhoso**:

```
print ("x=", x, "y=", y, "x+y*2=", x+y*2)
```

O ideal seria um comando simples, como:

```
debug (x, y, x+y*2)
```

... o qual acrescentaria o nome das variáveis automaticamente como no print acima.

O problema é que não vi uma forma de fazer isso.

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Problema que quando passado para a função, a referência ao valor muda, mudando também o nome. Por exemplo, você poderia definir a função `debug(*args)` para receber quantos parâmetros precisar, mas a variável passa a ser `args` e não mais `x`, `y` ou uma expressão. Para `x` e `y` você consegue trabalhar com o valor retornado por `locals()`, mas quanto a expressão, não sei se consegue fazer; talvez com `inspect`, precisaria analisar melhor.

Comment: eu normalmente nesses casos faço algo como print("A",x,y,z,w,p,n); (o A no começo é só pra saber de qual print se trata, num segundo eu ponho B, ou alguma coisa que faça sentido só pra diferenciar, pq eu sei o que eu pus dentro do print, não preciso deixar todas as strings "bonitinha" (afinal é debug né?). Agora, se você precisa toda hora de um monte de print, seria legal revisar a metodologia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como comentado, uma opção para exibir o *debug* de variáveis é utilizando o módulo [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html). Com auxílio da função [`inspect.stack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack) você consegue verificar o contexto de onde a função foi executada e acessar as variáveis locais e globais nesse contexto. Assim, ao invés de você passar a própria variável para função, você pode passar apenas o nome dela que a função se encarregará de acessar o respectivo valor por inspeção. Para este exemplo usei ainda o módulo [`tabulate`](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) para formatar a saída de forma fácil e legível.

```
import inspect
import tabulate


def debug(*args):

    # Busca o contexto de quem chamou a função debug:
    context = inspect.stack()[1][0]

    # Obtém detalhes de onde foi executado o debug:
    filename = context.f_code.co_filename
    linenumber = context.f_lineno

    # Resultados a serem exibidos:
    result = []

    # Percorre todas as variáveis a serem exibidas:
    for name in args:
        # Verifica se é uma variável local no contexto:
        if name in context.f_locals:
            result.append([name, context.f_locals[name]])
        # Verifica se é uma variável global no contexto:
        elif name in context.f_globals:
            result.append([name, context.f_globals[name]])
        # Variável não encontrada no contexto:
        else:
            result.append([name, 'Não encontrada'])

    # Exibe os resultados em forma de tabela:
    print(f'[DEBUG] {filename} ({linenumber})')
    print(tabulate.tabulate(result, headers=['Variável', 'Valor']))
```

Um exemplo de uso seria:

```
>>> x, y, nome = 1, 2, 'Anderson Carlos Woss'
>>> debug('x', 'y', 'nome', 'foo')
```

```
[DEBUG] python (34)
Variável    Valor
----------  --------------------
x           1
y           2
nome        Anderson Carlos Woss
foo         Não encontrada
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/GreenyellowSardonicUtilities)</sup>

**Exemplo de chamada dentro de uma função**

Fazendo o `debug` de uma variável local e outra global:

```
autor = "Anderson Carlos Woss"


def hello(nome):
    debug('nome', 'autor')
    print(f'Olá, {nome} (por {autor})')


hello('John Doe')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/DeterminedNextCode)</sup>

A saída será:

```
[DEBUG] python (37)
Variável    Valor
----------  --------------------
nome        John Doe
autor       Anderson Carlos Woss

Olá, John Doe (por Anderson Carlos Woss)
```

Porém, para a expressão, tal como fazer `x+y*2` a função não irá funcionar. É possível implementar a função para tal, mas acredito que será inviável. Será muito mais simples você atribuir a expressão a uma outra variável e passa-la para a função. Por exemplo:

```
>>> x, y = 1, 2
>>> x_plus_2y = x + 2*y
>>> debug('x', 'y', 'x_plus_2y')
```

Exibindo:

```
[DEBUG] python (38)
Variável      Valor
----------  -------
x                 1
y                 2
x_plus_2y         5
```

Comment: Fantástico. Isso deveria se transformar num novo comando nativo do Python! Obrigado.

Comment: @RogérioDec Não há muita necessidade visto que você pode muito bem definir essa função e usar nos seus projetos. Aliás, incrementei o código adicionando o nome do arquivo e o número da linha onde a função `debug` foi chamada, para facilitar caso tenha múltiplas saídas dessas. Nos exemplos o nome do arquivo ficou como `python` apenas por causa da estrutura do Repl.it.

Answer (score 8):

Você pode imprimir um dicionário com todas as variáveis locais se fizer  `print(locals())` .

Também, se não conhece, recomendo aprender a usar o [PDB (Python Debuger)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) - que permite que você acompanhe interativamente a execução do programa, e inspecione o valor das variáveis quando quiser. No Python 3.7, é só colocar `breakpoint()` no meio do código. Em qualquer versão anterior, a linha `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

Comment: Obrigado. A ideia seria apenas ter um comando simples e rápido para facilitar a depuração, uma vez que durante este processo não seria legal perder o foco construindo uma série de comandos apenas para depurar. Já uso o Pycharm que tem uma excelente depuração. O problema é que para acompanhar a evolução dos valores em tempo de execução, daí tenho que usar o print(), pois o debugger do Pycharm mostra os valores apenas durante um breakpoint. Daí entra minha pergunta, se tivesse um facilitador, algo simples.

Answer (score 0):

Eles estão dentro do módulo `logging`:

```
import logging
from random import randint

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.info('Iniciando o programa')

for i in range(0, 5):
    x = randint(0, 100)
    y = randint(0, 100)
    z = y if y > 100 else x
    logging.debug('x={}, y={}, z={}'.format(x,y,z))

logging.info('Finalizando o programa')
```

E o resultado seria algo assim:

`INFO:root:Iniciando o programa
 DEBUG:root:x=68, y=59, z=68
 DEBUG:root:x=65, y=38, z=65
 DEBUG:root:x=97, y=64, z=97
 DEBUG:root:x=15, y=26, z=15
 DEBUG:root:x=29, y=13, z=29
 INFO:root:Finalizando o programa`

Claro, elas são enviadas para STDERR mas você pode direcionar para um arquivo, assim como também customizar o que é exibido na mensagem e também definir o nível de registro (usando level=logging.INFO apenas a primeira e última mensagens seriam exibidas) para quando saber o valor das variáveis não for mais necessário. :-)

Comment: Bom saber. Mas a ideia era deixar o processo menos trabalhoso e com essa solução fica ainda mais trabalhoso do que digitar os nomes um a um dentro do print...

Answer (score 0):

Usar `eval` é a solução.

Aqui está minha nova função `debug`, que é simples. Você só precisa colocar os nomes das variáveis em uma lista de strings:

```
 def debug (vars):
     for var in vars:
         print (var, "=", eval (var))
```

Exemplo:

```
 t = "algum texto"
 n = 3.1416
 debug (['t', 'n'])
```

Resultado:

```
 t = algum texto
 n = 3.1416
```

Comment: A função debug assim so tem acesso as variáveis globais, ou, locais se ela for definida _dentro_ da função onde você estiver usando o debug. Para poder chamar essa função "debug" ou uma similar, pode passar pra ela o retorno de `locals()`, e aí imprimir as chaves que interessam:  `def debug(variables, var_names): print([(var_name, variables[var_name]) for var_name in var_names)`, e aí chamar com `debug(locals(), ['t', 'n'])`