# Como criar uma função "gatilho" quando uma variável muda de valor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variáveis, trigger, pygame

Observando [pygame.Surface.get_rect()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect), percebo que quando eu mudo uma variável, por exemplo `left`, pygame recalcula todas as variáveis da classe automaticamente (`center`, `right`, etc).

Eu gostaria de saber, como isso é feito?

Como é possível detectar a mudança de um valor de variável e a partir deste "trigger", acionar uma função?

Comment: off-topic, mas aproveitando o ensejo - ontem você fez uma pergunta pertinente sobre pygame, mas apagou-a quando ganhou um downvote- no entanto, ela tinha uma resposta válida. Eu acho isso um pouco chato para quem se deu ao trabalho de responder sua pergunta. Será que não consideraria "desapaga-la" ?

Comment: @jsbueno, não apaguei a pergunta por causa do downvote, mas porque eu tinha me enganado no teste que eu havia feito antes e postei uma pergunta errada de forma precipitada, sendo portanto a pergunta desnecessária. Peço desculpas.

Comment: ok - de qualquer forma, a resposta lá incluía uma coisas que eu não conhecia. (eu posso ler ainda - não me lembro a partir de quantos pontos de reputação é possível ler postagens excluídas)

Comment: @jsbueno, encontrei o post e consegui "desdeletar": https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/333332/110948

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O Pygame não usa nenhuma técnica especial no fluxo do código, como "callback", nos retângulos - é apenas um exemplo bem planejado de uso de properties.

Seguinte: Python tem um mecanismo chamado de "descriptor protocol" - que permite que o acesso a atributos de uma instância ou de uma classe seja customizado. Funciona se um atributo de classe for um objeto que ele mesmo tiver um método dentre `__get__`, `__set__` ou `__del__`.

Para facilitar ainda mais o uso desse mecanismo, a linguagem tem o built-in `property`, que normalmente é usado como um decorator.

No caso de um retângulo como o do pygame, é uma questão de escolher quais dados vão ser armazenados internamente no retângulo, e em seguida escrever o código dos getters e setters na forma de properties para todas as propriedades que desejamos expor. Por exemplo, para manter fazer "left, top, width, height" como atributos reais, e expor a propriedade, que pode ser alterada "right", tudo que é necessário é:

```
class Rect:
   def __init__(self, seq):
        self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height = seq

   @property
   def right(self):
        return self.left + self.width

   @right.setter
   def right(self, value):
        self.width = value - self.left
```

O legal de usar descriptors, mesmo com o simplificador "property" é justamente que o usuário do seu objeto não percebe a diferença de estar simplesmente lendo ou setando um atributo.

No caso específico do pygame.Rect, o código da classe é escrito em C, e aí os getters e setters são menos genéricos de se escrever do que com um descriptor feito em Python puro. O código fonte está online aqui: 
https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/master/src_c/rect.c

As funções de getters e settesr das propriedades começam a ser escritas a partir da linha 1247, são associadas às propriedades em si na struct que começa na linha 1625 e são por fim associadas à classe na linha 1696. Você pode ver que as funçõezinhas para poder inspecionar vários valores do retângulo, e alterar alguns todas operam apenas nas propriedades "reais" "x, y, w, h", como fiz no exemplo acima para a propriedade "right".

(Esse arquivo do rect.c do Pygame é um que provavelmente poderia ser re-escrito em Cython e ficar com cerca de 1/5 do mesmo tamamho e a mesma performance - o interessante dele ser em código nativo, é que assim as  funções de verificação de colisão podem verificar facilmente centenas de retângulos por frame sem "cansar" uma CPU moderna)