# Erro: "illegal target for variable annotation" usando "@property"

Tags: python, python-3.x, getters-setters, pygame, pycharm

Como `pygame` não dispõe de uma função semelhante à biblioteca [SFML -> View](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-view.php), estou desenvolvendo um formato de "câmera" para fazer o scroll da tela e preservar as posições dos objetos dentro da coordenada geral dentro do "mundo".

Como padrão do `pygame`, usa-se o [retângulo](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html).

Para facilitar a manipulação, quero alterar as variáveis `left` e `top` obtidas no [get_rect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect), acrescentando o offset da câmera a estas variáveis.

Seguindo este [exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/333831/110948) de @jsbueno, estou com uma dificuldade:

Tenho uma classe `class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite)` e dentro dela pego o retângulo de uma imagem e armazeno `self.ret = self.imagem.get_rect()`. Daí, quero devolver um valor diferente de `self.ret.left` toda vez que esta variável for acessada.

Mas ao declarar `@property` e logo abaixo `def ret.left(self):` eu recebo `illegal target for variable annotation`.  Qual seria a sitaxe correta neste caso?

```
import pygame

class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, imagem, x, y):
        self.imagem = pygame.image.load('imagem.png')
        self.ret = self.imagem.get_rect()

        @property
        def ret.left(self): # aqui aparece o erro
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que seria esse `self.ret` dentro da classe, entre os dois métodos? Ele está indentado errado ou era para ser assim mesmo? Quanto ao erro, `ret.left` não deveria ser `ret_left`?

Comment: Nomes de `funções` ou `métodos` não permitem uso do caractere `.`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, desculpe, foi um erro de edição, já corrigi. `ret` é uma instância da classe `pygame.Surface.Rect` (https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect)

Comment: Eu gostaria de saber como eu posso intereceptar a leitura da variável `self.ret.left` usando `@property`?

Comment: Melhorei a pergunta original no começo para deixar mais claro qual meu objetivo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como eu disse no comentário a nomeação `funções/métodos` não permite o uso do caractere `.`, por isso o erro de sintaxe. O que você pode fazer é com o método decorado com `@property` retornar a instância da classe `pygame.Surface.Rect` da seguinte forma:

```
import pygame

class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, imagem, x, y):
        self.imagem = pygame.image.load('imagem.png')
        self._ret = self.imagem.get_rect()

    @property
    def ret(self):
        return self._ret
```

Permitindo então fazer `self.ret.left`, mas que convenhamos não possui nenhum sentido, visto que `ret` já é um atributo da instância `self.ret.left` já está acessível. A não ser que você pense em implementar um `setter` para esse atributo, onde se faria necessaria então esse `getter`.
Uma alternativa seria:

```
import pygame

class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, imagem, x, y):
        self.imagem = pygame.image.load('imagem.png')
        self.ret = self.imagem.get_rect()

    @property
    def ret_left(self):
        return self.ret.left

    @property
    def ret_right(self):
        return self.ret.right
```

Comment: Na verdade aprendi agora há pouco a lógica de `@property`. Seu exemplo não estava funcionando, mas daí percebi que o problema no seu código é na identação. Os 2 `@property` de seu exemplo tem que estar alinhados com o `def __init__`.

Comment: Não tinha notado a identação. Obrigado.