# Como obter o nome do pai da função python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Fala, Povo!

Tenho uma função de adcionar log - add_log() -  que recebe um titulo, status e obs para registar em um arquivo txt junto com o horario.

Gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de pegar o nome da função pai em que o add_log() é chamada.

Ex:

```py
def Soma(a,b):
    try:
        return a+b
    except:
       add_log() #add_log recebe Soma no parâmetro mida sem precisar passar 

>>> '12:09:18.3544 Soma() - OK'
```

````py
import datetime


def getnow():
    return str(datetime.datetime.now())[:24].split()


def add_log(media,status,obs=""):
    path = '../logs/{}.txt'.format(getnow()[0])
    arq = open(path,'a+')
    arq.write('{} {} - {} - {}'.format(getnow()[1],media,status,obs).strip().strip('-')+'\n')
```

0
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode utilizar o módulo [`inpect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) para isso. Com ele você pode obter o *stack* de execução até a sua função `add_log` e, a partir dele, descobrir quem fez a chamada à função. Para isso, utilizamos a função `inpect.stack`, que retorna uma lista de tuplas nomeadas, `FrameInfo`, sendo a primeira posição a função atual e a última a função que iniciou a *stack*. Neste caso, como nos interessa apenas a função mãe, podemos pegar a posição 1:

```
import inspect

def foo():
    add_log()

def add_log():
    stack = inspect.stack()

    try:
        print('Função mãe:', stack[1].function)
    except KeyError:
        print('Função mãe não encontrada')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/EasygoingHappyVirus)</sup>

Ao chamar a função `foo`, `foo()`, a saída `Função mãe: foo` é produzida pela função `add_log`.

Fora isso, você consegue obter o nome do arquivo e o número da linha em que ocorre essa chamada, como já mostrei em [Debug mostrando nome e valor da variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/333260/5878)

Answer (score 0):

Olá!
Creio que utilizando os recursos do python para tal necessidade, será mais proveitoso...

O pacote logging, traz funcionalidades para registro de atividades já implementados, cabendo somente aplicá -Los da melhor forma para nosso código.

Segue exemplo totalmente customizável!

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s -  %(funcName)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO,
                    datefmt='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S')


def soma(a, b):
    try:
        r = a + b
        logging.info(f'resultado: {r}')
        return r
    except TypeError:
        logging.error("deu ruim", exc_info=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    soma(1, 2)
    soma(1.2, 2.1)
    soma('a', 'b')
    soma('', 2)
```

Saída:

```
15-May-19 07:03:34 - INFO -  soma - resultado: 3
15-May-19 07:03:34 - INFO -  soma - resultado: 3.3
15-May-19 07:03:34 - INFO -  soma - resultado: ab
15-May-19 07:03:34 - ERROR -  soma - deu ruim
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/brito/projetos/saj_projects/exemplos/me/_logging/sof_pt_383625.py", line 11, in soma
    r = a + b
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Para persistir em arquivo basta alterar a configuração do logging, e acrescentar os paramentros **filename** e  **filemode** como no exemplo em: https://repl.it/@britodfbr/i383625

Mais detalhes na documentação oficial em https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html, e um tutorial detalhado em https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html.